# VS Code open directory instead of system file manager in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: mime-type, visual-studio-code

After upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 I notice a stranger behaviour in code: if I double click a directory or a unit or right click a directory and try open the directory was open by code unless nemo or nautilus.

I install code by [microsoft repo](https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/) after add the repo to apt

I do not know if is a microsoft or gnome or ubuntu problem.

but this behaviour is not friendly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a workaround to temporary solve the problem.

find
`~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`
and be sure the inode/directory= was set to your file manager.

exemple:
`inode/directory=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop;`

same for file `~/.config/mimeapps.list`

then find the code desktop file.
mine is in `/usr/share/applications/code.desktop`
and change the row

`MimeType=text/plain;inode/directory;`
to
`MimeType=text/plain;`

then do
`$ sudo update-desktop-database`

to me this work but if vscode is updated all reset to the initial behaviour.

The `/usr/share/applications/code.desktop` is revert to initial value.

So to make all more quickly I write a script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 sudo sed -i "s/inode\/directory;//" /usr/share/applications/code.desktop
 sudo update-desktop-database
```

waiting for stable solution this may be acceptable

### Update

I have put the script above in an `after-upgrade-code.sh` and change in this manner (I put it inside PATH env):

```
#!/bin/bash
UPDATED="$(tac /var/log/apt/history.log|sed '/End-Date/,$!d;/Start-Date/q'|tac|grep 'Upgrade.*code')"
if [[ ! -z $UPDATED ]]
then
  sudo sed -i "s/inode\/directory;//" /usr/share/applications/code.desktop
  sudo update-desktop-database
fi
exit 0
```

the I put it `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/100update`:

```
Post-Invoke {"after-upgrade-code.sh";};
```

If last apt upgrade make change on code it will upgrade the code.desktop

### Update

I have done some test and I not be sure if the postinvoke script work fine: the problem is that I not sure history.log was updated at Post-Invoke time, so the script can do noting if history is not updated.

This is version 2 and this will be trigger:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
CHECK="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')" 
CHECK="${CHECK:0:-1}.*upgrade code"
UPDATED=$(sudo grep "$CHECK" /var/log/dpkg.log)
#UPDATED="$(tac /var/log/apt/history.log|sed '/End-Date/,$!d;/Start-Date/q'|tac|grep 'Upgrade.*code')"
if [[ ! -z $UPDATED ]]
then
  sudo sed -i "s/inode\/directory;//" /usr/share/applications/code.desktop
  sudo update-desktop-database
    echo "after-update-code is been executed"
else
    echo "after-update-code is been not executed"
fi
exit 0
```

This: `CHECK="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')"` get the date time taking only minute.
This: `${CHECK:0:-1}` cut minute unit and leave the ten so
the grep: `grep "$CHECK" /var/log/dpkg.log`
check if an 'Code' upgrade was done in less then ten minute and if verified try to  update the code.desktop to avoid 'Code' will be use to open folder.

I have changed the hook trig:
`sudo cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/100update`
give:
`DPkg::Post-Invoke {"/home/leonardo/sviluppo/script/after-upgrade-code.sh";};`

### Update

I have do a mistake writing the `UPDATED` wrong (`UPTDATED`), now is correct.

### Uptate

Last version work: I have verified :-)

Comment: In my case (KDE Plasma + nautilus), just modifying `/usr/share/applications/code.desktop` (then `update`) did the trick.

Comment: the script is to avoid to do it manually all the time :-)

Comment: Indeed. I just wanted to point out that was enough. Actually I couldn't find mimeapps.list in /.local and there were no code.desktop in /usr mimeapps. That caused me half an hour of useless internet wandering.

Comment: This behaviour by code is inacceptable. I don't want to open directories by default in vscode.

Answer (score 4):

Copy file:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/code.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/code.desktop
```

And edit `~/.local/share/applications/code.desktop`:

`MimeType=text/plain;inode/directory;application/x-code-workspace;`

to

`MimeType=text/plain;application/x-code-workspace;`

Comment: This was enough for me too, a lot cleaner than the default answer

Comment: Thank you, I spent just a half of a minute going through your solution and it works just nice, even though I'm not an ubuntu user - I'm a Manjaro Gnome user, so since it's the same Gnome - it works as it considered to do

Answer (score 3):

In gnome, you can use this command for set natural folder browser as default:

```bash
xdg-mime default org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop inode/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Check also the mimetype `inode/mount-point`:

```
xdg-mime query default inode/mount-point
```

if it's empty the vscode could opens the mountpoint; set your filemanager to the default mimetype for mount point:

```
xdg-mime default org.kde.dolphin.desktop inode/mount-point
```